# Convert Y axis in Python dash

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a data from csv file

| id | lap_time | LapNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 175 | 0 days 00:02:04.853000 | 2 |
| 176 | 0 days 00:02:01.375000 | 3 |
| 177 | 0 days 00:01:59.889000 | 4 |
| 178 | 0 days 00:01:58.425000 | 5 |
| 179 | 0 days 00:01:57.786000 | 6 |
| 180 | 0 days 00:02:10.329000 | 7 |
| 181 | 0 days 00:01:53.315000 | 8 |
| 182 | 0 days 00:01:49.771000 | 9 |

when I try to display a graph with a dash

```
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import pandas as pd
import fastf1
from fastf1 import plotting
import plotly.express as px
...
...
        dcc.Graph(
            figure={
                "data": [
                    {
                        "x": lec['LapNumber'],
                        "y": lec['LapTime'],
                        "type": "lines",
                    },
                ],
                "layout": {"title": "Test Date"},
            },
        ),
...
```

Unfortunately I gets [incorect plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgLoD.png)

When I do the same using go.figure:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=lec['LapNumber'], y=lec['LapTime'])])
```

I got [correct plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH2JX.png)

Do you know how to solve this issue on dcc.Graph ?
Need to add some parameters to X axis ?

Thanks for hint

Comment: The y-axis in go.Figure is not the same as in dcc.Graph

Comment: Y-axis in go.Figure is in the format of number in billion and in dcc.Graph is in the format of a timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this approach:

```
from dash import dcc
import plotly.graph_objs as go

fig = go.Figure([go.Scatter(x=lec['LapNumber'], y=lec['LapTime'])])

dcc.Graph(figure=fig)
```